# (Yocto) openblas recipe fails : do_package_qa: QA Issue: -dev package openblas-dev contains non-symlink

Tags: yocto, openblas, yocto-recipe

I am trying to build a recipe **openblas.bb** for the OpenBLAS library but it fails at **package_qa** stage.
The machine is : **zynqmp-generic**, the poky version is **langdale**.

You could find **openblas.bb** file here: https://textdoc.co/OuIzyN8ijXBMQeRx .

And here it is the error from ***log.do_package_qa***:

```
ERROR: QA Issue: openblas rdepends on openblas-dev [dev-deps]
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-staticdev
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-locale
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-lic
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-doc
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-dev
NOTE: aarch64-xilinx-linux-objdump -p /some/path/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/openblas/0.3.26-r0/packages-split/openblas-dev/usr/lib/libopenblas.so
NOTE: aarch64-xilinx-linux-objdump -p /some/path/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/openblas/0.3.26-r0/packages-split/openblas-dev/usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.3.26.so
ERROR: QA Issue: -dev package openblas-dev contains non-symlink .so '/usr/lib/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.3.26.so' [dev-elf]
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-src
NOTE: Checking Package: openblas-dbg
NOTE: aarch64-xilinx-linux-objdump -p /some/path/build/tmp/work/cortexa72-cortexa53-xilinx-linux/openblas/0.3.26-r0/packages-split/openblas-dbg/usr/lib/.debug/libopenblas_armv8p-r0.3.26.so
ERROR: Fatal QA errors were found, failing task.
DEBUG: Python function do_package_qa finished
```

Thanks in advance :)